# Meet a girl at tinder, she's asking for me to wire transfer in her name

Tags: scams, wire-transfer

So I meet this girl on tinder, after a few weeks of chatting she tells me that she's sending me her bank account info (by the way the bank doesn't looks legit it's Ukraine base) and want me to transfer money to her suppliers. I already search her photos and I found the original girl. Already know it's not her. But how is this a scam? She's giving me her bank account and then asked me to transfer to another person that it also looks fake, the name of the bank it's demolium international bank, Google it and it suppose to be in Ukraine. But web page also looks suspicious. The person that it's receiving the transfer it's in India. And she's passing as a US army soldier.

Comment: Nothing she told you is true, including the fact that it's her own bank account details she's giving you.

Comment: man really.....

Comment: You know it's a scam.  Understanding how the scam works is not necessary.  Some scams even count on people playing along in the hopes of figuring it out, only to be trapped by the time they do.  Just walk away and rest assured you dodged the bullet.

Answer (score 3):

> But how is this a scam?

It may not be her Bank account,  but someone else's that is hacked.  So if tracked it would be you have done it... although unlikely...

It could also be initial set up to see if someone is interested... it can then take a turn , looks like some issues with my account,  can I use your account... transfer my salary and you send this to suppliers,  parents etc...

Answer (score 0):

The scam is simple. The person you are corresponding with is not who they say they are. Any money you send will not go to whatever purpose that person says it is for, and you will never get it back. It will also never lead to any meeting in real life with the person you are corresponding with.